# Basemap streamplot blank sphere

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I want to make a streamplot in Basemap module, but I get a blank sphere. Please help me resolve this problem. I use matplotlib 1.3 and ordinary streamplot is working fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

map = Basemap(projection='ortho',lat_0=45,lon_0=-100,resolution='l')

# draw lat/lon grid lines every 30 degrees.
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,30))
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30))

# prepare grids
lons = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
lats = np.linspace(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, 100)
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

# parameters for vector field
beta = 0.0
alpha = 1.0

u = -np.cos(lats)*(beta - alpha*np.cos(2.0*lons))
v = alpha*(1.0 - np.cos(lats)**2)*np.sin(2.0*lons)
speed = np.sqrt(u*u + v*v)

# compute native map projection coordinates of lat/lon grid.
x, y = map(lons*180./np.pi, lats*180./np.pi)

# contour data over the map.
cs = map.streamplot(x, y, u, v, latlon = True, color = speed, cmap=plt.cm.autumn, linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly tell you what's wrong, but from the matplotlib.streamplot manual:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot(x, y, u, v, density=1, linewidth=None, 
color=None, cmap=None, norm=None, arrowsize=1, arrowstyle=u'-|>', 
minlength=0.1, transform=None, zorder=1, hold=None)¶

Draws streamlines of a vector flow.

    x, y : 1d arrays
        an evenly spaced grid.
    u, v : 2d arrays
        x and y-velocities. Number of rows should match length of y, and the number of columns should match x.
```

Additionally from matplotlib.basemap.streamplot you can read that

```
If latlon keyword is set to True, x,y are intrepreted as longitude and  latitude in degrees.
```

Which corresponds to the fact that x and y should be 1D arrays (lat, lon). However in your example x and y are

```
>>> np.shape(x)
(100, 100)
>>> np.shape(y)
(100, 100)
```

Then again you call the method map() "to compute native map projection coordinates of lat/lon grid" which is coincidentally the same as the name of your basemap.map. So it depends on which one do you want? Because both will return a value! (or better to say, both will return an error)

Aditionally check out the values you have in your u array. They are of range e-17. While other values are easily in the range e+30. IIRC the way you get streamlines is by solving a differential equation in which points you sent it as values are used as parameters at coordinates you sent. It's not hard to imagine a that while calculating something with these numbers a floating point round-off occurs and you suddenly start getting NaN or 0 values.

Try to scale your example better or if you want to pursue the solution to the end you can try and use [np.seterr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) to get a more detailed idea where it fails.

Sorry I couldn't have been of a bigger help.